# control an application window's place (on top, to the bottom...) in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

In Java, a method opens a browser:

```
desktop.browse(uri);
```

How can I control for the position of the browser window: I need to put it on top, but also to get it back to the background at some point (for user experience improvements).

Comment: I doubt it's possible. You telling the OS to open a web page, Java might not even know which browser will be launched. If the browser has command-line arguments for setting the required settings, you should be able to use [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) (though you'd obviously be sacrificing platform+browser-independence by making the browser location explicit).

Comment: That seems only feasible in your own application, **Swing HTML** is limited. **JavaFX has a nice WebView** and is embeddable in swing. Or maybe you could make a **file system frameset HTML** which loads the real URL and does in JavaScript positioning and resizing of the browser window. Can be blocked in most browsers I guess.

Comment: Your comment led me to the JavaFX solution. Thx

Comment: Could you turn your comment into a question, so that I can accept it?